# how to hide status bar when splash screen appears in iphone?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, splash-screen, statusbar

Is there a way to hide the status bar when showing splash screen in iPhone
and then show again in application?

Answer (score 192, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that if your Info.plist file has the `Status bar is initially hidden` value set to `YES`, then it won't show while your application is loading.  Once your application has loaded, you can re-show the status bar using UIApplication's `setStatusBarHidden:animated:` method.

Comment: there is no such option in info.plist.is there a way to add it manually

Comment: @Rahul select the last line in thefileand then click the plus button over on the right end of the line. Then type it in yourself.

Comment: The method re-show the status bar is now, setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation:

Comment: Should you want to add it manually, you can edit the plist in a text editor like BBEdit and add the lines:  <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
 <true/>      just above the </dict> line. Or in Xcode right click on the plist and choose Open As...Source Code and edit it as text.

Comment: "Once your application has loaded, you can re-show the status bar" Just to clarify if anyone is confused, it's safe to set `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];` on - application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

Comment: like @RyanRomanchuk said, in iOS 9 and Swift, set status bar hidden to false like this: ```UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarHidden = false``` in ```application:DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions```

Comment: In my case just add key View controller-based status bar appearance: YES, in Plist and delete the app and re-run app. It works!!

Answer (score 48):

The correct key in .plist is "UIStatusBarHidden" and make checked right side.It'l become "Status bar is initially hidden" then automatically. In my practice, you can control the StatusBar's　show/hide anywhere by when hide:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:NO];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480); //full screen.
```

when show:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:NO];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.frame=CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460); //move down 20px.
```

hope this was helpful to you.

Comment: To dynamically setting the size of the CGRectMake to any type of iPhone:

    `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO withAnimation:NO];`
    
    `float width  = ((UIScreen *)[UIScreen mainScreen]).bounds.size.width;`
    `float height = (((UIScreen *)[UIScreen mainScreen]).bounds.size.height - 20);`
    
    `[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, width, height);`

Comment: UIApplication's `setStatusBarHidden:withAnimation` is expecting a NSInteger typedef `UIStatusBarAnimation` for the second argument, not a BOOL. Instead of `NO`, use `UIStatusBarAnimationNone`

Answer (score 23):

View -> Property List Type -> iPhone Info.plist. Now, make a new item with "Status bar is initially hidden" checked.

Answer (score 6):

Following up Dave's answer the key "Status bar is initially hidden" didn't work for me under iOS 4.3 BUT the key "UIStatusBarHidden" and then setting it's type to Boolean and checking the box did the trick.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009254-SW4

This developer article got me onto the Info.plist keys and then working out the equivalent key for hiding it wasn't too hard.

Interestingly the "UIStatusBarStyle" needs to use the enumeration name as a string for it to work.

Answer (score 6):

For Xcode 5 and above you can just set:

View controller-based status bar appearance to NO

In your info.plist, or in the info tab on your main project.

[image: Example of Info settings in xcode]

Answer (score 3):

write this 1 line in to your main .m viewDidload method

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:NO];
```

or select info.plist file from your project supporting files folder in workspace

set statusbarinitialyhidden to YES

Answer (score 2):

is deprecated

```
setStatusBarHidden:(BOOL) animated:(BOOL)
```

is the correct

```
setStatusBarHidden:(BOOL) withAnimation:(UIStatusBarAnimation)
```

**UIStatusBarAnimation** which can be:

*UIStatusBarAnimationNone* or *UIStatusBarAnimationFade* or *UIStatusBarAnimationSlide*

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in the info.plist:

```
"View controller-based status bar appearance"  -> set to NO
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `Status bar is initially hidden` to `YES` in the `info.plist` file. This worked for me.

[image: status bar hidden]

Answer (score 0):

For XML editors ~ add to first  child of

```
<key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
```