# Default.png is shown below status bar region, want to make it full screen

Tags: iphone, fullscreen, default.png

As asked in the title,

My Default.png is displayed below status bar region.
Status bar area is blacked out.

How can I make the default.png to be shown in true full screen.

- edit

It's not duplicate question as the ones linked.

"Status bar is initially hidden" is checked in my info.plist already.
I don't see status bar, just the area where status bar resides appear black when default.png loads.
I must add I see this happening in iphone 3g with ios 3.1.2, other devices I tested works fine.

Comment: please don't put tags in your titles, it's redundant with the tags.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to hide status bar when splash screen appears in iphone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147706/how-to-hide-status-bar-when-splash-screen-appears-in-iphone)

Answer (score 0):

when the app is designed for iOS7 with Xcode5, just select the option:Target->[Your App Name]->General->DeployMent Info->Hide during application  launch.It's perfect for iOS7,but if you want to fit with iOS6,it's necessary  for you to add the code behind in the method :

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions;

the code is:

application.statusBarHidden = NO;