# Hiding the statusbar iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to hide the statusbar on the landingpage of my app only. I figured this is the right function and it does get executed, however the status bar still remains there

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()

    self.prefersStatusBarHidden()
}

override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: see this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38876249/cant-hide-status-bar-swift-3/38876435#38876435

Comment: `self.prefersStatusBarHidden` That is wrong (and pointless). You _never_ call this method.

Comment: Can you explain why I should never call this method? I want my statusbar hidden on my landingpage only.

Comment: remove this line, self.prefersStatusBarHidden(). @RutgerHuijsmans

Comment: self.prefersStatusBarHidden() remove this line and all shall work well

Comment: Try this: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147706/how-to-hide-status-bar-when-splash-screen-appears-in-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Add below entries in info.plist

> View controller-based status bar appearance -> YES
>
> Status bar is initially hidden -> YES

[image]

And In ViewControllers, In which you want to hide the StatusBar, Write below method.

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {  
    return true  
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Wolverine

Answer (score 0):

Set value "No" for key "View controller-based status bar appearance"  in plist file

and No need to call "self.prefersStatusBarHidden()" manually so remove it from viewDidAppear